# Outlook add-ins dialog latency issue

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

We are building outlook add-ins. We use the dialog javascript API to open a dialog from the Task bar. There is a latency of 4 to 6 seconds in opening the dialog. Is there a way to speed up the loading time. It is independent of the content we are loading.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know if you are using this method：

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myAddinDomain/myDialog.html');
```

Or you You can create a new simple project(Word/Outlook add-in) to test the load speed. 
For details, see [Use the Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md)

Hope it helps you.